# MPMoviePlayer Default Control Buttons are unaligned

Tags: iphone, controls, mpmovieplayer

I have an MPMoviePlayer, which need to work on all iOS from 3.1 and forward. I modify the showing of controls based on the iOS version but I always use the default controls (i.e. setting control style for iOS 3.2 and 4 models, and control mode for 3.x versions).

A strange issue happens on the iOS 3.2+ MoviePlayer. The Rewind button is displaced some 5 or ten pixels up making it unaligned with the rest of the buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so in this case it turned out that my attempt to change content type and controlStyle didn't turn out very well. One solution I found if this issue appears is to create a completely new instance of the MPMoviePlayer and setting up the controlStyle accordingly...